# Barometric pressure - not getting values

Tags: android, pressure

I've read the [Environment Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment.html#sensors-using-temp) documentation so I'm trying to get the `pressure`, but unsuccessfully.

This is what I have:

```
public class Pressure extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

TextView textView;
private SensorManager sensorManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_pressure);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_pressure);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Service.SENSOR_SERVICE);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE) {
        float[] values = event.values;
        textView.setText("" + values[0]);
    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Does you phone or device have the sensor? Its been my experience that sensors vary wildly from device to device; and I have never encountered a pressure sensor in the wild. (I use the sensors to seed my random number generators, so I look at them often).

Comment: I thought my galaxy ace had it.... ahaha. My code is ok, i tried on the note3. Watching it running I'm noticing that the value changes continously, is there a way to stop it? Perhaps after two decimals?

Comment: Very good (and thanks for the tip on where to find a device with that sensor). I moved to close as a "could not duplicate", but its still a good question, so my +1 stands.